# Is "I'm on Heathrow airport" correct?

Tags: prepositions

Is  "I'm **on** Heathrow airport" correct? I mean is it correct to use the preposition "on" here?

With "I'm on Heathrow airport" I meant being inside the main building/terminal, I know the usual preposition for that is "in" ("I'm in the airport"), but can I also say "I'm on Heathrow airport" for that meaning ?

Comment: We might have some duplicate/related posts available, at least for extra reading.

Answer (score 2):

Generally not -- this would suggest you were standing on the roof.

"At Heathrow Airport" or possibly "In Heathrow Airport" (if you were in a specific building) would be the usual form.

Comment: Or by *Heathrow airport* you are actually describing the runway—or the ground, *on* which you (or the plane) is located. (*I'm **standing on** Heathrow airport*.) It would have the exactly the same structure as *I'm **standing on** holy ground*.) But, you're right. *At* is far more likely.